# Migrating Task Queues to Cloud Functions

Tags: node.js, python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-functions, task-queue

We're using [Google App Engine Standard Environment](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/) for our application. The runtime we are using is [Python 2.7](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/). We have a single service which uses multiple versions to deploy the app.
Most of our long-running tasks are done via [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/). Most of those tasks do a lot of [Cloud Datastore](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/overview) CRUD operations. Whenever we have to send the results back to the front end, we use [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) for that.

I wanted to try out [Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/) for those tasks, mostly to take advantage of the serverless architecture.
So my question is What sort of benefits can I expect if I migrate the tasks from Task Queues to Cloud Functions? Is there any guideline which tells when to use which option? Or should we stay with Task Queues?

PS: I know that migrating a code which is written in Python to Node.js will be a trouble, but I am ignoring this for the time being.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apart from the advantage of being serverless, Cloud Functions respond to specific [events](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/events-triggers) "glueing" elements of your architecture in a logical way. They are elastic and scale automatically - spinning up and down depending on the current demand (therefore they incur costs only when they are actually used). On the other hand [Task Queues](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/taskqueue/) are a better choice if managing execution concurrency is important for you:

> Push queues dispatch requests at a reliable, steady rate. They
>   guarantee reliable task execution. Because you can control the rate at
>   which tasks are sent from the queue, you can control the workers'
>   scaling behavior and hence your costs.

This is not possible with Cloud Functions which handle only one request at a time and run in parallel. Another thing for which Task Queues would be a better choice is handling retry logic for the operations that didn't succeed.

Something you can also do with Cloud Functions together with [App Engine Cron](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/config/cron) jobs is to run the function based on a time interval, not an event trigger.

Just as a side note, Google is working on implementing Python to Cloud Functions also. It is not known when that will be ready, however it will be surely announced in [Google Cloud Platform Blog](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/).

Comment: Looks like I should stay with Task Queues for the time being.